# What is the square root of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

If matrix A is positive definite and symmetric. **Can I use cholesky Factorization to find the square root of A?**

:by cholesky factorization ,A=LDL' where L is a low triangular matrix ,D is diagonal matrix, then square root of A is Ld where d is the matrix which square root all the term in D.

Is it correct?

**Is there an algorithm for finding square root of A which is not symmetric?**

thanks

Comment: @user1551: hmm, I misspoke; I meant nonnegative, not positive. (By contrast, a symmetric matrix with nonnegative eigenvalues always has a square root.) An explicit example is $\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the" square root of a matrix.  A matrix may have infinitely many square roots, or none.  A positive definite (symmetric) matrix has a unique positive definite symmetric square root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algroithm for finding square root of $2 \times 2$ square matrix

**See here**
http://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Square_Roots-Sullivan13884.pdf

Important is the Cayley-Hamilton theorem which states that a matrix over a commutative ring satisfies it's own charactristic polynomial.

The primary result is:

$$ A = X^2$$

$$X = \epsilon_2 \frac{A+\epsilon_1 \sqrt{det(A)}I}{\sqrt{tr(A)+2\epsilon_1\sqrt{det(A)}}}$$

where $I$ the identity and $\epsilon_i=\pm 1$.

Comment: Donald Sullivan's paper from Mathamatics Magazine "The square roots of $2\times 2$ matrices".